# javascript ajax variable question

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hey there, new to AJAX, JS.. Im trying to add to a Javascript/Ajax search script that I've put together. Previously, it had a single search field, called search_word, I added one called search_date.

```
$(".search_button").click(function() {
    var search_word = $("#search_box").val();
    var search_date = $("#datepicker").val();
    var dataString = 'search_word='+ search_word;

    if(search_word=='')
    {
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "searchdata.php",
        data: dataString,
```

In the Ajax, it appears to pass data of dataString, to my processing script. How do I add search date to the dataString so that I can use that var in my searchdata.php?

In searchdata, I can do this $search_word=$_GET['search_word']; and use that var, but so far every time i attempt to alter the dataString, it breaks all the other functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

```
var dataString = 'search_word='+search_word+'&search_date='+search_date;
```

Or you can get rid of that line completely and just do

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "searchdata.php",
        data: {search_word: search_word, search_date: search_date}
      });
```

Comment: The second option i tried but it wouldnt post. The first option worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Also, if you're more used to working within "GET", you can send out the string 'foo=bar&foo2=bar2' etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `dataString` like so:

```
var dataString = 'search_word='+ search_word + '&search_date=' + search_date;
```

I also suggest you invert your if condition, to `if(search_word) { ... }`, put the AJAX in there, and skip the `else`.

If this doesn't help you, try alerting out the value of `dataString` after that concatenation, to see what is really happening. perhaps the value of `search_date` is not what you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'search_word='+ search_word + '&search_date'+search_date;
dataString = encodeURI(str);

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "searchdata.php",
    data: dataString});
```

> > #### To avoid unexpected requests to the server, you should call [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURI) on any user-entered parameters that will be passed as part of a URI.

Comment: you'd have to use `encodeURI` or, preferably, `encodeURIComponent` on the two parameters individually, and not on the final concatenated string. the current solution will replace the `&` in `&search_date=` with `%26`, and the equal signs will be replaced by `%3D`. (the operative part of your bold text being *on any user-entered parameters*, not on the entire final querystring; that wont work at all)

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly add it to the url:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "searchdata.php?search_word=" + search_word;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your $.ajax call you can use an object for the data parameter.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "searchdata.php",
        data: {search_word: search_word, search_date: search_date}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the data a json object with your parameters:

```
data {
  prop1: val1
  , prop2: val2
}
```